# Ruby on Rails: Class.where(...) but return just 1 record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a table named users, and I'm doing

```
array = User.where("username=?", username)
```

to get the user for a specific username.

My minor gripe is that this returns an array, and I have to do `array[0]` but there should always be just 1 user returned.

Is there anyway, syntactically to specify that I expect just 1 record, and it shouldn't be an array returned, just the user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can limit it to one result:

```
User.where("username = ?", username).first
```

However, you might just want to use the dynamic `find_by_` method:

```
User.find_by_username(username)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use the limit in the case you want to get more results, but limiting.

```
User.where("username = ?", username).order('created_at DESC').limit(5)
```

Comment: thanks, I also needed to know how to order by as well! hehehe

Answer (score 0):

Here is another syntax to find the first record

```
 array = User.find(:first,:conditions => {:username => username})
```